# Align the corner and make the walls symmetrical in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Is there any way to even out the wall thickness in **edit mode**? It is important to repeat the distance between the edges so that the angle is symmetrical.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, how does the whole mesh look like? maybe try extrude along normals?

Comment: Perhaps this would work, but the walls given in the example already initially have different thicknesses. Extrude along normals will initially turn out to be asymmetric.

Comment: Are they aligned with the X and Y axes? Then I would for example select the edges in Y direction, hit G, X to move them along X and snap them to the outer edge. Press Enter to confirm their position. Now with them still selected (will be tricky to select them afterwards when they're overlapping), hit G, X again and enter a value like .1 (or -.1 depending to go to the other side) to move it an exact distance. Do this accordingly for the other edges in X direction by moving them with G, Y.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the hint, now everything has worked out.